# Finding intersection of Pandas dataframes within range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

A project I'm working on requires merging two dataframes together along some line with a delta. Basically, I need to take a dataframe with a non-linear 2D line and find the data points within the other that fall along that line, plus or minus a delta.

#### Dataframe 1 (Line that we want to find points along)

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('path/to/df1/data.csv')
df1
```

```
         x        y
0     0.23     0.54
1     0.27     0.95
2     0.78     1.59
...
97    0.12     2.66
98    1.74     0.43
99    0.93     4.23
```

#### Dataframe 2 (Dataframe we want to filter, leaving points within some delta)

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv('path/to/df2/data.csv')
df2
```

```
          x        y
0      0.21     0.51
1      0.27     0.35
2      3.45     1.19
...
971    0.94     2.60
982    1.01     1.33
993    0.43     2.43
```

#### Finding the coarse line

```
DELTA = 0.03

coarse_line = find_coarse_line(df1, df2, DELTA)
coarse_line
```

```
          x        y
0      0.21     0.51
1      0.09     2.68
2      0.23     0.49
...
345    1.71     0.45
346    0.96     0.40
347    0.81     1.62
```

I've tried using `df.loc((df['x'] >= BOTLEFT_X) & (df['x'] >= BOTLEFT_Y) & (df['x'] <= TOPRIGHT_X) & (df['y'] <= TOPRIGHT_Y))` among many, many other Pandas functions and whatnot but have yet to find anything that works, much less anything efficient (with datasets >2 million points).

Comment: Can you provide useable data samples?  `head()` of the two data frames where there are intersections.  Normal approach to working with continuous data when you want to match it is put it into bins `pd.cut()`

Answer (score 1):

Have taken an approach of using `merge()` where x,y have been placed into bins from *good* curve `df1`

1. generated a uniform line, *y=x^2*
2. randomised it a small amount to generate `df1`
3. randomised it a large amount to generate `df2` also generated three times as many co-ordinates
4. take `df1` as reference for good ranges of x and y co-ordinates to split into bins using `pd.cut()`.  bins being 1/3 of total number of co-ordinates is working well
5. standardised these back into arrays for use again in `pd.cut()` when merging

You can see from scatter plots,  it's doing a pretty reasonable job of finding and keeping points close to curve in `df2`

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, sharey=True, sharex=False, figsize=[20,5])
linex = [i for i in range(100)]
liney = [i**2 for i in linex]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[l*random.uniform(0.95, 1.05) for l in linex], 
              "y":[l*random.uniform(0.95, 1.05) for l in liney]})
df1.plot("x","y", kind="scatter", ax=ax[0])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[l*random.uniform(0.5, 1.5) for l in linex*3], 
              "y":[l*random.uniform(0.5, 1.5) for l in liney*3]})
df2.plot("x","y", kind="scatter", ax=ax[1])

# use bins on x and y axis - both need to be within range to find
bincount = len(df1)//3
xc = pd.cut(df1["x"], bincount).unique()
yc = pd.cut(df1["y"], bincount).unique()
xc = np.sort([intv.left for intv in xc] + [xc[-1].right])
yc = np.sort([intv.left for intv in yc] + [yc[-1].right])

dfm = (df2.assign(
    xb=pd.cut(df2["x"],xc, duplicates="drop"),
    yb=pd.cut(df2["y"],yc, duplicates="drop"),
).query("~(xb.isna() | yb.isna())") # exclude rows where df2 falls outside of range of df1
 .merge(df1.assign(
    xb=pd.cut(df1["x"],xc, duplicates="drop"),
    yb=pd.cut(df1["y"],yc, duplicates="drop"),
 ),
        on=["xb","yb"],
        how="inner",
        suffixes=("_l","_r")
 )
)
dfm.plot("x_l", "y_l", kind="scatter", ax=ax[2])
print(f"graph 2 pairs:{len(df2)} graph 3 pairs:{len(dfm)}")
```

[image]